# How to remove HTTP headers from CURL response in Java

Tags: java, http, parsing, web, http-headers

I need to remove HTTP headers from the parsed web pages in Java.

```
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2009 14:10:05 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
    Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Jun 2009 17:40:52 GMT
    ETag: "18ac11-d16-46b610b465100"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 3350
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

As shown above, first few lines are http headers.
I need to get rid of them to process parsed pages, but then, I'm not sure on how to do it since headers vary in length and in contents.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Hint: HTTP-Headers end with `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Do you have to use CURL for reading the data?

Comment: Thanks, but  I can't just get rid of strings end with \r\n\r\n since contents might have them as well. Can I avoid risking losing some of contents while using regex?

Comment: Mick // Yes I do, I'm working on parsed pages (lots of them), and it was parsed by someone else.

Comment: tkausl// Oh, sorry. You meant, whole HTTP-Headers end with \r\n\r\n. I misunderstood that each header line ends with that. I gotta try this. Thanks

Comment: You say "cURL response". If you don't need headers, why not invoke `curl` **without** a `-i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get index of e.g. `<html` and substring this String.

```
text.substring(text.indexOf("<html"))
```

Comment: True for web pages, but some of the parsed contents were images (raw bytes), and had no html tags. I managed to do it by parsing first \r\n\r\n